# TinyMCE Menu & Toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I'd like to modify the "Formats" menu and toolbar in the TinyMCE editor so that I can make nested picks - just like in the example on the TinyMCE homepage (tinymce.com).

For example, under formats, I'd like to create three groups called headers, tables and fonts. Under each of these groups, I'd like to add various style formats.

I know how to create the different style formats I need, but I don't know how to create the "nested" menus in TinyMCE, and I can't find any examples of this on the TinyMCE website.

Here is a snippet of the code I have now:

```
style_formats: [
        {title: 'Header H1', block: 'h1'},
        {title: 'Header H2', block: 'h2'},
        {title: 'Header H3', block: 'h3'},
        {title: 'Header H4', block: 'h4'},
        {title: 'Header H5', block: 'h5'},
        {title: 'Header H6', block: 'h6'},
        {title: '8 Pt Font', inline: 'span', classes: 'font8'},
        {title: '10 Pt Font', inline: 'span', classes: 'font10'},
        {title: '12 Pt Font', inline: 'span', classes: 'font12'},
        {title: '14 Pt Font', inline: 'span', classes: 'font14'},
        {title: '16 Pt Font', inline: 'span', classes: 'font16'},
        {title: '18 Pt Font', inline: 'span', classes: 'font18'},
        {title: 'Vertical Align Top', selector: 'td', classes: 'cell1'},
        {title: '10 px Image Padding', selector: 'img', classes: 'img10'},
        {title: '20 px Image Padding', selector: 'img', classes: 'img20'},
        {title: '10 px Video Padding', selector: 'iframe', classes: 'vid10'},
        {title: 'Gray Cell', selector: 'td', classes: 'td-gray'},
        {title: 'Red Cell', selector: 'td', classes: 'td-red'},
        {title: 'Yellow Cell', selector: 'td', classes: 'td-yellow'},
        {title: 'Green Cell', selector: 'td', classes: 'td-green'},
        {title: 'Blue Cell', selector: 'td', classes: 'td-blue'}
]
```

I'd like to break this into logical groups. Can someone show me to do this in the tinymce.int?

Thank you!